# Get name of parent shape when click on a child shape

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 grouped shapes named “Group1” and “Group2”, each contains 2 shapes named “Rectangle1” and “Rectangle2”.

When I click on “Rectangle1” in any of the 2 grouped shapes, it always return “Group1” (which comes first in order).

Is there anyway to return the grouped shape name of that specific child shape without changing its name?

Thank you.

```
Public Sub ReturnParentName()
   Dim shp as Shape

   Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ParentGroup
   MsgBox shp.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: .Name will return the child shape name not the the parent name.

Comment: In what context do you try returning the name in discussion? In a sub assigned to a group specific shape? Otherwise, `Applicatin.Caller` does not return anything.

Comment: I have many child shapes assigned to the same public sub.

Comment: So, the implicit answer is Yes, in a sub called by the shape in discussion... Is this understanding correct? If yes, please look to the answer I posted.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in this way, please:

```
Sub CommonProcedure_Click()
   Debug.Print Application.Caller 'the shape name
   Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Parent.Name      'the sheet keeping the shape/group name
   If ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Child Then
        Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ParentGroup.Name
    Else
        Debug.Print "Not in a group..."
    End If
End Sub
```

In order to automatically change the name of identically named shapes, you can use the next code. It needs to add a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'. It can be done using late binding, but it should be good to benefit of intellisense suggestions, I think:

```
Sub changeShapesSameName()
   Dim sh As Shape, shG As Shape, dict As New Scripting.dictionary
   For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
       If sh.Type = 6 Then
            For Each shG In sh.GroupItems
                    If Not dict.Exists(shG.Name) Then
                        dict.Add shG.Name, shG.Id
                    Else
                        If dict(shG.Name) <> shG.Id Then shG.Name = shG.Name & shG.Id
                        dict.Add shG.Name, shG.Id 'only to see the sheets balance at the end
                    End If
            Next
       Else
            If Not dict.Exists(sh.Name) Then
                    dict.Add sh.Name, sh.Id
            Else
                    If dict(sh.Name) <> sh.Id Then sh.Name = sh.Name & sh.Id
                    dict.Add sh.Name, sh.Id       'only to see the sheets balance at the end
            End If
       End If
   Next
   Debug.Print dict.count            'total number of individual shapes
   Debug.Print Join(dict.Keys, "|")  'dictionary keys (all shapes name)
   Debug.Print Join(dict.items, ":") 'dictionary items (all shapes IDs)
End Sub
```

If the necessary reference is not already added, the next code will automatically add it:

```
Sub addScrRunTimeRef()
  'Add a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime':
  'In case of error ('Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project not trusted'):
  'Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings->Macro Settings->Developer Macro Settings->
  '         check "Trust access to the VBA project object model"
  On Error Resume Next
  Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll"
  If err.Number = 32813 Then
        err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox "The reference already exists...": Exit Sub
  Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox """Microsoft Scripting Runtime"" reference added successfully..."
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: .ParentGroup.Name always return “Group1” even if the clicked shape is “Rectangle1” in “Group2”. If I reorder the 2 grouped shapes to make “Group2” below “Group1” it will always return “Group2”.

Comment: @user3286479 Only if there are more shapes **with the same name**. Is this the reality in your sheet?

Comment: Yes. Each group contains a shape with the same name “Rectangle1”. Is there any workaround to resolve this problem without changing the name of one of them?

Comment: @user3286479 I am afraid, not. The code defines the object according to the shape name in the active sheet. Theoretically it returns the first object matching the name, or an array of shapes. I cannot reproduce the situation. Can you share the workbook in discussion? Or try explaining how did you "succeed" to give the same name to the shapes on the same sheet? I am not able do do it... Theoretically, Excel must not allow that, but I heard that in some circumstances it does. I cannot reproduce your case.

Comment: I use Excel 2016 and there is no problem in defining the same name for multiple shapes in the same worksheet.

Comment: @user3286479 I had a problem with this issue (Excel 365), but it can be done if you copy a shape from another sheet, having the same name with an existing one. I think I can imagine a piece of code able to automatically modify the similar shapes name, making them unique...

Comment: So it’s impossible to achieve that without changing names?

Comment: @user3286479 I am afraid that it is impossible. Because the shape returned by `ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)` is the first found shape having that specific name. I edited the answer and posted a sub able to automatically change all the identic names. Even if identic names, the shapes `ID` is different. But you cannot determine it, if not able to firstly reference the correct shape... You can adapt the code to use a different suffix, if this will help better. I used the ID, which certainly will make the concatenation creating a unique name.